How to re-start the Primary Native HA MQ instances from Replica
while testing failover, I started a Replica Native HA Queue Manager instance, How do I flip back to primary HA instance?
I need to get back to normal primary Native HA instance
I have tried endmqm, strmqm with all parameters.... not working!
QMNAME(hub)                                               STATUS(Replica)
bash-4.4$ strmqm -x hub
IBM MQ queue manager running as replica instance
